# Как сделать так, чтобы в одной и той же функци осуществлялась работа с разными типами данных?

Tags: c++, математика, матрицы, типы-данных

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы в функции осуществлялась работа с разными типами данных. Есть функция для создания двумерного массива и заполнения его случайными числами. Но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы, например, при первом вызове функции создался массив с элементами типа int, а при втором вызове массив с элементами типа double. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/436880/

Comment: Посмотрите на шаблоны, вероятно, это то, что вам нужно. Правда, формально будут сгенерированы две разные функции, но писать вам придется только одну :)

Comment: А на сколько правильный такой подход?

Comment: Если код в целом одинаковый, отличающийся разве что небольшими деталями — вполне верный. Если это принципиально разный код, который хочется завернуть в одну функцию... то надо подумать, а оно точно нужно? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблоны - весьма часто используемый аспект языка c++, и даже его стандартная библиотека называется STL - Standard Template Library. Так что на вопрос "насколько правильный такой подход" можно ответить - что да, правильный.

Вы в вопросе упомянули:

> чтобы, например, при первом вызове функции создался массив с элементами типа int, а при втором вызове массив с элементами типа double

Так нельзя. Тип шаблона определяется не тем, каким по счёту разом вызвана функция, а типами переданных в неё параметров.

```
template<typename T>
void fillRandom(T *arr, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = 42; //думаю, как генерировать случайные числа различных типов, разберётесь сами
    }
}
```

Вызывать так:

```
float *a = new float[100];
fillRandom(a, 100); //В старых версиях C++ потребуется такая запись: fillRandom<float>(a, 100);
```

Comment: `как генерировать случайные числа различных типов, разберётесь сами` - ммм... это действительно несложно? Я не плюсовик, и вижу выход в проверке `std::is_integral`. Или всё проще?

Comment: @MBo, Насколько мне известно, не проще, только это заслуживает отдельного вопроса. В зависимости от того, что вернёт `std::is_integral_v<T>`, нужно будет подставить либо `std::uniform_int_distribution`, либо `std::uniform_real_distribution`.

Comment: ОК, понятно. Или здесь по месту делать ветвление кода, или шаблонизированный генератор СЧ, в котором то же самое.

Comment: К тому же я уверен, что автор вопроса использует функцию `rand`. Если столкнётся с тем, что она не даёт вещественных чисел, и задаст вопрос - подскажем.